# How to notify two different controllers to update their views simultaneously in MVC 6?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am fairly new at working with MVC 6 so I have a question in regard to views and controllers. I am trying to understand a simple concept, which in WPF is fairly easy to do using an Event Aggegator, Observable, or other similar patterns.

Suppose we have a category view which renders a list of categories. We also have a products view which renders a list of products.

When the page first loads the category view renders all (or most of) parent categories, while the products view renders a list of products that bear a flag `LandingPageProducts = true`.

When the user clicks on a major category, the view that renders the categories should refresh by loading all child categories, including a "go back" link. Furthermore the products view renders the products for the particular selected category, regardless of what sub categories they live in.

Clicking on a child category within the categories view once again renders its own child categories within the category view and updates the products view with products that are specific to that category (and it's sub children).

My question is if I have the two views, how would the two controllers know to update simultaneously? Or is the categories view posting to a parent controller somehow responsible for rendering both views?

I am trying to maintain two controllers because I want to be able to preserve the selected category when the user clicks on the product within the product view. The product view should render details for the product without having to concern itself with what categories are rendered into the category view. While I can possibly do this out of a single controller, I am also aware that there is a lot of state information I have to pass back and forth between each view which is something I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Is it a same page inside which you which you want to show both the categories and the products ?

Comment: Yes. This is a hypothetical e-commerce store.

Comment: You should use ajax to load the sub category for the selected category as user clicks on a category. Do the same thing for the products.

Comment: I am still learning how to do this. I am not sure how to make this work with ajax as well. I mean I used to develop e-commerce stores back in the day with asp.net, Microsoft Commerce server and JQuery but things have changed in the last 5-6 years.

Comment: As far as I can understand, your assumption is probably not correct. MVC and MVVM are two different patterns. In MVVM the view is somewhat connected to to view model. But in MVC, it does not work that way. Controller and View work independently. Unlike WPF, there is no common "notify" mechanism in MVC. You have to use your own methods to do that. You can use knockout, AngularJS etc to make MVC work like MVVM.

Comment: I am aware they work independently. This is why I am asking a suggestion how to make this work. As far as I know when the user clicks on a product or a category the link itself posts to the controller responsible for that data. But how do you post to both controllers, or force the two views to update simultaneously? Or notify either the controllers that their selection has changed so they can return a corresponding view?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: You need to have a fundamental understanding that web pages are not like application forms.  They may seem like it, but each http request to the controller is its own little universe.  Once a page is rendered, there is no longer any connection and the controllers and views are all destroyed until the next time a web request is made.

Comment: I am aware of that. Like I said I still know about classic ASP.NET - each request and view rendered goes through a series of events, state is carried in the HttpContext, Session State and View State, each with different lifespan and scope. However the geniuses behind MVC changed quite a bit of that... and it appears classic ASP.NET is kind of dead. This leaves people like me... back to the basics. (Thank you Microsoft.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stateless Web works different than stateful webforms/WPF apps.

I guess what you are looking for is dynamically updating the products/subcategory when user selects a category. You can do this with ajax.

So in the initial page load you should list the categories ( and default products if you want) in your main view and when user clicks on a category, make an ajax call to get the sub categories and add that to the page. Do the same thing for products as well. When user clicks a sub category, pass the clicked sub category id and get the products belongs to it.

Assuming you have a view model like this

```
public class YourPageVm
{
  public List<ItemVm> Categories { set;get;}
  public YourPageVm()
  {
     this.Categories = new List<ItemVm>();
  }
}
public class ItemVm
{
  public int Id { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your action method for your page, you create an object of this view model and load the initial categories you want to show and send it to the view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var vm = new YourPageVm();
  //Hard coded for demo. Replace with data from your db
  vm.Categories.Add(new ItemVm { Id=1, Name="Phones" });
  vm.Categories.Add(new ItemVm { Id=2, Name="Books" });
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now in your view

```
@model YourPageVm
<h3>Categories </h3>
@foreach(var cat in Model.Categories)
{
  <div class="catContainer">
    <a class="cat" 
         href="@Url.Action("Subcategories","Category",new { id=cat.Id})">@cat.Name</a>
    <div class="subCategoryContainer" />
   </div>       
}
```

Now have some javascript-jquery code to listen to the click event on the category links, make an ajax call with the category id and the action method you are calling should return the partial view markup for the sub categories and add that to the dom.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
     $(document).on("click","a.cat",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url=$(this).attr("href");
        $(this).closest(".catContainer").find(".subCategoryContainer").load(url);
     });
  });
</script>
```

Assuming you have an action method called `Subcategories` in your `CategoryController` which accepts the Id and return the partial view for the sub categories

```
public ActionResult Subcategories(int id)
{
  // using the id, get subcategories for that categoryId 
  // and pass that to the view of this action method
  return PartialView();
}
```

You need to the same thing for the products for a sub category as well.

Comment: So return PartialView sends the sub-categories view (html) back to JQuery which inserts it in the div or whatever element is supposed to render it. Is there even a point to doing this with MVC? It seems to me that all I really need to have are the controllers. I should probably invest my time into researching single page application concept with Angular 2/JQuery...

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery or javascript based framework to do that. In jquery you can do it this way;

Let's assume you have a drop down called category.

```
$("#category").on("change", function(evt)
{
    evt.preventDefault();
    var selectedCategory= {category:value1};
    var categoryController = "\Category\GetSubcategoriesByCategory";
    var productController= "\Product\GetProductsByCategory";

    $.get(categoryController,selectedCategory,function(response1){          
        $("#divcategories").html(response1); //refresh category partial view
    });

    $.get(productController,selectedCategory,function(response2){
          $("#divproducts").html(response2); //refresh products partial view
    });
});
```